# Easy way to compute logarithms without a calculator?

Tags: logarithms

I  would need to be able to compute logarithms without using a calculator, just on paper. The result should be a fraction so it is the most accurate. For example I have seen this in math class calculated by one of my class mates without the help of a calculator.

$$\log_8128 = \frac 73$$

How do you do this?

Comment: If you are asked to do so, the result will be something simple that you can do using the laws of logs. In this case it is important that $128=2^7$.  You should look for powers you know when doing these.

Comment: You could have written a more interesting example. What about $\ln(200.34)$ or $\log_{11}(4)$?

Comment: @KimPeek The poster is likely a student who has recently studied logs and wishes to solve introductory exercises with exact answers. I do not believe the poster intended to approximate *any* logarithm.

Comment: slide rule works for me...

Comment: @Joel he said **without** a calculator :-)

Comment: And without tables, of course.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

To evaluate $\log_8 128$, let 
$$\log_8 128 = x$$
Then by definition of the logarithm, 
$$8^x = 128$$
Since $8 = 2^3$ and $128 = 2^7$, we obtain
\begin{align*}
(2^3)^x & = 2^7\\
2^{3x} & = 2^7
\end{align*}
If two exponentials with the same base are equal, then their exponents must be equal.  Hence,
\begin{align*}
3x & = 7\\
x & = \frac{7}{3}
\end{align*}

Check:  If $x = \frac{7}{3}$, then 
$$8^x = 8^{\frac{7}{3}} = (8^{\frac{1}{3}})^7 = 2^7 = 128$$

Answer (score 42):

Using $\log_xy=\dfrac{\log_ay}{\log_ax}$ and $\log(z^m)=m\log z$ where all the logarithms must remain defined unlike $\log_a1\ne\log_a(-1)^2$

$$\log_8{128}=\dfrac{\log_a(2^7)}{\log_a(2^3)}=\dfrac{7\log_a2}{3\log_a2}=?$$

Clearly, $\log_a2$ is non-zero finite for finite real $a>0,\ne1$

**See** [Laws of Logarithms](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Laws_of_Logarithms)

Answer (score 12):

As you've seen, it can be a bunch of work to actually calculate them by hand. So, in the context of "no calculator", I'd like to point out that the [slide rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slide_rule) was made almost exactly for this type of calculation!

Comment: The slide rule **is** a calculator. A mechanical calculator.

Comment: So how do you calculate logarithms with a slide rule?   (No fair using the log scale or the loglog scales.)  One way a slide rule can help is by providing accurate first approximations for the square roots that you need if you want to do the log by binary bracketing.  A slide rule is also helpful in interpolating from a table.

Comment: Further, a slide rule facilitates interpolation when you are using a table.

Answer (score 10):

Another way of doing this:

$$ 128= 2^7 = (2^3)^\frac{7}{3} = 8^\frac{7}{3}$$

$$ \log_8 128 = \log_8 (8)^\frac{7}{3} = \frac{7}{3}$$

Note the laws of logarithm used here: $$ \log_a a = 1$$

$$ \log_y x^a= a \log_y x$$

Answer (score 8):

In general, this works only if the base of the logarithm is a power of some number. If it is, then write the base $b$ as $x^a$ for some integers $x,a$. Then try to write the argument of the log as $x^c$ for some integer $c$. Then the answer to the logarithm would be $\frac{c}a$.

For example,
$$\log_{8}(128) = \log_{2^3}(2^7)=\log_{2^3}((2^3)^{\frac73})=\frac73$$
 $$\log_{27}(2187) = \log_{3^3}(3^7)=\log_{3^3}((3^3)^{\frac73})=\frac73$$

$$\log_{36}(216) = \log_{6^2}(6^3)=\log_{6^2}((6^2)^{\frac32})=\frac32$$

Answer (score 6):

All the answers have focused on the specific example you provide, but the numerical techniques involved readily apply to other examples as well. If you desire to obtain  $\sqrt 3 $ note that:

$\ 7^2 = 49 \approx 48 = 3 * 16 = 3 * 4 ^ 2$

thus

$\ 3 \approx  7^2 / 4 ^ 2 = (7/4) ^ 2$

and taking the square root of both sides we yields

$\sqrt 3 \approx 7 / 4 = 1.75 $

Similarly for $\sqrt 2 $ note that $\ 10 ^ 2 = 100 \approx 2 * 49 = 2 * 7 ^ 2 $ and so $\sqrt 2 \approx 10 / 7 = 1.4 $

After some practice you will be able to get approximations within 1% very quickly, often in your head.

When pencil and paper are available one can often quickly double the precision through a single iteration of [Newton's Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method). For example:

$ \sqrt 2 / 1.4 \approx 1.42857 $ and so a better approximation is $ \sqrt 2 \approx (1.4 + 1.42857)/2 = 1.414285 $.

Repeating again gives $ \sqrt 2 \approx 1.41421356 $, which is as accurate as many hand calculators.

Comment: The question was about logarithms, not square roots...

Comment: Could you explain your "and so"? Both times it comes out of nowhere.

Comment: @hawkeye: Done.

Answer (score 3):

This answer is additional to awesome answers already given, especially, that of N. F. Taussig.

The definition of a logarithm in reals may help: $\log_b a$ is such a real number $c$ that satisfies $b^c = a$. For example, $\log_2 131072 = 17$ because $2^{17} = 131072$.

Also, you may want to be able to calculate natural logarithms without a calculator. I will tell you a method that I use: since $e^3 \approx 20$, you can take $\ln 20 \approx 3$. Hence, to calculate $\ln n$ in practical applications, first calculate $\log_{20} n$, then multiply it by $3$. Since $20$ is an integer, it's easier to work with. For example, if we need to calculate $\ln 34 627 486 221$, we can do the following:

$$20^8 = 2^8 10^8 = 25 600 000 000\\ \log_{20} 25 600 000 000 \approx 8\\ \ln 25 600 000 000 \approx 8 \cdot 3 = 24\\ \ln 34 627 486 221 = \ln 25 600 000 000 + \ln (34 627 486 221 / 25 600 000 000) \approx 24 + \ln 1.35 \approx 24.35$$

The answer is only 0.13% off, which is very accurate.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

In Apostol’s Calculus textbook, volume 1, the computational formula for the logarithm is developed. The specific example of $\log 2$ is given, obtaining the result
$0.6921 < \log 2 < 0.6935$ “with very little effort," as Apostol remarks.

> “You have no idea, how much poetry there is in the calculation of a table of logarithms!”
>   -- Carl Friedrich Gauss

Comment: This answer fails to give any information in how to obtain this result without a copy of this book.

Answer (score 0):

Try

$$\ln(x) = \lim_{n \to \infty} n \left( x^{1/n} - 1 \right)$$

If $n$ is a power of $2$, you get to take a lot of square roots.  See the HHC 2018 proceedings for a paper on the computation of logarithms.

Generally, power series are efficient for natural logarithms of numbers near $1$.  You can do things to get your number near $1$, such as multiplying by a power of ten or taking the square root, then adjusting the logarithm you get.

Meanwhile, memorize the number $0.4343$.   That is the approximate logarithm of $e$.  Use that to convert natural logs to base ten logs.

Comment: Knuth offers a method that uses SQUARING instead of taking the square root.  This can be much easier, but unless you carry a lot of digits, the algorithm goes bad.  Investigation of this is assigned as a 20 point problem.  Assume your number is between 1 and the base.   Square it.   If the square is still less than the base, write a zero.  Otherwise write a 1 and divide the square by the base.   Repeat until you can't stand it any more.  What you have is the log in binary.  A good way to investigate this is to simulate it in a spreadsheet to see where things go wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the edit.  I'll try to learn mathjax one of these days.